# Python: read 'bytes' in the shape of console output (unknown encoding)

Tags: python, byte

I have a `bytes` object which, when `print()`ed, looks like this `b';\x7f\x07\xfe\xa5\x8ek\x07\xd4\xac?\x11\xd6\x8b\xe5\x81g\xd2G\x0f%\ ...'`

I'd like to be able to do something like

`bytes_ = bytearray(b';\x7f\x07\xfe\xa5 ...')` in order to get the exact same object that I've printed.

The encoding of the `bytes` object is unknown. What are my chances here?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the byte? The byte itself retrieved should have the sufficient information for you to recreate it without transforming it (at least to my understanding).

Comment: I have to isolate it in order to provide it to a client but it's not coming from my server so I in fact don't know what's in it